# How to have two source captions in a ggplot2 graph?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to add a second caption in my ggplot2 graph. 
Similar to how this graphic was done by this economist

[image]

Here is a basic plot I made where I know how to add one caption on the bottom right, but how can I add another one to the bottom left

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes( mpg, hp)) +
  geom_point() +
  labs(title = "MTCARS MPG ~ HP",
       caption = "Source: mtcars dataset")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As usual you have two options - either annotation outside the plot, or you create two (or three!) plots and combine them.

Both options require a bit of trial and error. Hopefully you won't need that very often and not need to fully automate it depending on different scales etc.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(patchwork)

textframe <- data.frame( #making the frame for the text labels.
    x = c(-Inf, Inf),
    y = -50,
    labels = c("Source1: mtcars dataset", "Source2: Not mtcars dataset"))
```

**option 1 annotation outside the plot**

```r
# requires manual trial and error with plot margin and y coordinate... 
# therefore less optimal

  ggplot(mtcars, aes( mpg, hp)) +
  geom_point() +
    geom_text(data = textframe, aes(x, y, label = labels), hjust = c(0,1)) +
    coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0,350), clip = 'off') +
    theme(plot.margin = margin(b = 50, 5,5,5, unit = 'pt'))
```

[image]

**option 2 Two plots**, combining them. Here using `patchwork`. I personally prefer this option.

```r
p1 <- 
  ggplot(mtcars, aes( mpg, hp)) +
  geom_point() 

p2 <- 
  ggplot(mtcars, aes( mpg, hp)) +
    geom_blank() +
    geom_text(data = textframe, 
              aes(x, y = Inf, label = labels), 
              hjust = c(0,1), 
              vjust = 1) +
    theme_void() 

  p1/p2 +plot_layout(heights = c(1, 0.1))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-04-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: How do you make "textframe" if  the x-axis is dates? Because -Inf won't work with dates

Comment: @arv - maybe worth a follow up question. if you decide to post, please don't forget to link to this question.