# Two subtitles in two different positions in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

In ggplot I have two figures made by facet_wrap and I would like to have two subtitles Versicolor and Virginica left aligned to each figures. How is it possible? I tried James Allison's [How to add multiple captions in ggplot2 outside of the main graph area](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47025729/how-to-add-multiple-captions-in-ggplot2-outside-of-the-main-graph-area) solution but it was a single figure. Here is what I tried, but I did not get what I want.

```
iris %>% filter(Species != 'setosa') %>% 
ggplot(aes(x= Petal.Length, y= Petal.Width))+
  geom_point()+
  facet_wrap(~ Species)+
  theme(strip.text.x = element_blank())+ # to get rid of grey box with species names
  labs(subtitle = 'Versicolor') # adding virginica
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to fake your subtitles using the strip text:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr, warn = FALSE)
iris %>%
  filter(Species != "setosa") %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Petal.Length, y = Petal.Width)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(~Species) +
  theme(
    strip.background.x = element_blank(),
    strip.text.x = element_text(hjust = 0, size = 11)
  )
```

[image]

Comment: I found another option but your's was the best. ```# Add subtitles manually using 'cowplot'
library(cowplot)
iris_with_species <- ggdraw(iris_p) +
  draw_label("Versicolor", x = 0.05, y = 1.01, hjust = 0, vjust = 1, size = 12) +
  draw_label("Virginica", x = 0.52, y = 1, hjust = 0, vjust = 1, size = 12)

iris_with_species```

Comment: Yep. For more complicated stuff  `cowplot` or `patchwork` are useful. But for your particular use case I think using the strip text is the easiest approach.